# Pylint logging-not-lazy issue?

Tags: python, pylint

```
filename_format = prefix + startdate.strftime('%Y%m%d') + '_' + enddate.strftime('%Y%m%d')
LOGGER.info('Filename format: ' + filename_format)
```

Ffor above, I'm getting

> specify string format arguments as logging function parameters (logging-not-lazy)

When I run pylint. Which section is the error?

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
filename_format = prefix + startdate.strftime('%Y%m%d') + '_' + enddate.strftime('%Y%m%d')
LOGGER.info('Filename format: %s', filename_format)
```

or:

```
filename_format = prefix + startdate.strftime('%Y%m%d') + '_' + enddate.strftime('%Y%m%d')
LOGGER.info('Filename format: {0}'.format(filename_format))
```

Comment: sweet the first one worked! thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. So, if it solves your problem, set the answer as the best one, please.